# Django (production server) LESS not rendering

Tags: css, django, html, less

I am running a Django website, when I deploy to the production server, the LESS file is loaded but not rendered, everything works fine in the local server, any idea why?

[image: LESS file not rendered]

[image: Network traffic all ok]
[image: Expected outcome / on local machine]

Answer (score 0):

You'd normally compile/transpile your Less file into CSS and include the CSS in your project, rather than including your Less file.

```
npm install -g less
lessc base.less > base.css
```

It is possible to compile the Less file in your browser by including [less.js](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage) but this is not recommended in production.